# Execute multiple functions in parfor

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

Currently I have several functions, named `function1.m`, `function2.m`, `function3.m` , ..., `function10.m`. Each function is independent each other. I would like to run the all the functions in one execution

currently, my code is like this, it runs the functions one by one.

```
for i = 1 : 10
  result = eval(sprintf('function%d.m',i));
  fprintf('%d ', result);
end
```

I would like to know is there a way to rewrite the code in `parfor` instead of `for`, as I know that `eval` does not work in `parfor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval` in a normal loop to populate a cell array of function handles?

```
functions = cell(10, 1);
for i=1:10
  functions{i} = eval(sprintf('@()function%d', i));
end
parfor i=1:10
  result = functions{i}();
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `eval` at all to create a cell array of function handles using a `for` or `parfor` loop. Then all you need to do is to call each function handle stored in `functions` cell array.

```
functions = cell(1, 10);

parfor i = 1:10
    functions{i} = str2func([ 'function', num2str(i) ]);
end

parfor i = 1:10
    result = functions{i}();
    fprintf('%d ', result);
end
```